# Which hypothesis test to perform?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I’ve got a problem figuring out which hypothesis test to perform,how many to perform, AND how my null, and -alternative hypothesis should be articulated.
The assignment: “The data set behind this assignment, consists of measurements of 303 patients, all of whom have been rushed to hospital with heart problems.”
“The chol-level(serum cholesterol mg/dl.) should be between 125 and 200, for a high value can cause heart disease. Therefore, investigate whether it can be demonstrated that the chol level for this type of patients is higher than 200. In addition, investigate whether the standard deviation of chol can be assumed to be 40.”

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: quite a number of people are beginning to doubt whether cholesterol is a cause of heart disease, or if it might be the reverse: heart disease is a cause of high cholesterol (that is, cholesterol is the body's way of fighting heart disease).

Answer (score 1):

The story line about patients being rushed to hospital is
unclear.

(a) Perhaps assume cholesterol levels are normally distributed
and do a one-sample t test of $H_0: \mu \le 300$ (or just $H_0: \mu = 300)$ against $H_a: \mu > 300.$

(b) Still assuming normality, test $H_0: \sigma=40$ against $H_a: \sigma \ne 40.$ Or possibly, make a 95% CI for $\sigma$ to see if it contains $\sigma = 40.$

You might have data somewhat similar to the fictitious
data sampled below in R:

```
set.seed(1130)
x = rnorm(303, 320, 50)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  164.9   282.9   318.0   317.4   350.1   470.4
```

For (a): The sample mean of the $n = 303$ patients is (about) $\bar X = 317.4 > 300.$ The question is whether this is *significantly* greater
than 300, in a statistical sense, at the 5% level.

Results
of a t test include P-value very nearly $0,$ which is smaller than $0.05 = 5\%,$ so with your 303 patients, you have
enough information to reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a.$

```
t.test(x, mu = 300, alt="g")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 5.7821, df = 302, p-value = 9.203e-09
alternative hypothesis: 
 true mean is greater than 300
95 percent confidence interval:
 312.4439      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 317.4126
```

For (b), a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is based on the
relationship $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1),$ where $S^2\approx 2748$ is the sample variance. It can
be obtained using R as $(2357,3245).$

```
(302)*var(x)/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 302)
[1] 2357.347 3244.805
```

A 95% CI for $\sigma$ is found by taking square roots of
the above CI for $\sigma^2,$ which gives $(48.55,56,.96).$
So it is reasonable to assume that the population standard deviation, from which my fictitious sample was taken, is not $\sigma=40.$

```
sqrt((302)*var(x)/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 302))
[1] 48.55251 56.96319
```

A two-sided, one-sample variance test would
be based on the same relationship using $\mathsf{Chisq}(302).$

From your question it is not clear whether you are supposed to
say what analysis to perform or to use actual data for tests
and/or confidence intervals. I hope you can match what I have
done with what is in your text or class notes, in order to
complete this assignment.